Diophantine equation of sixth degree
Show that the following equation admits infinitely many solutions:
$$x^3 + 2 y^6 - 2 z^6 = 1,\qquad \gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(y,z)=1.$$
For example, $(79,5,8)$ is a solution .

Next time, please use TeX on this site.

How do you know that the equation has infinitely many solutions? If the statement is false, your request cannot be fulfilled. Note also that this is a question-and-answer site. So please ask a question.

Let $F_k$ be the $k$-th Fibonacci number. Cassini's identity is $F_{k-1}F_{k+1}-F_k^2=(-1)^k$, hence $F_{k-1}^2+F_{k-1}F_k-F_k^2=(-1)^k$. Raising this to the third power and reordering terms yields
\begin{equation}
2(F_{k-1}^6-F_k^6)+(F_k^2+F_{k-1}F_k-F_{k-1}^2)^3=(-1)^k,
\end{equation}
which explains infinitely many pairwise coprime integer solutions.
See also sequence A337929 at the OEIS.

There is an Identity shown below:
$(a^2+ab-b^2)^3+(a^2-ab-b^2)^3=2(a^6-b^6)$ ---- (1)
We are given:
$x^3 + 2 y^6 - 2 z^6 = 1$
And we get "OP" equation by taking:
where,
$x=(b^2-ab-a^2)$
$y=a$
$z=b$
& we take, $(a^2-ab-b^2)=1$
For, $(a,b)=(5,3)$ we get $(x,y,z)=(-31,5,3)$
For, $(a,b)=(-2,3)$ we get $(x,y,z)=(11,-2,3)$
For, $(a,b)=(5,-8)$ we get $(x,y,z)=(79,5,-8)$
(The third solution is the one suggested by "OP").
